# usb credit card reader for Cocoa Application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, credit-card

I am creating an application that requires a credit card reader but I don't know where to find one that will work with objective c or any other language that will be compatible with the cocoa application. It is for desktop.

Thanks

Comment: You just need to do your own search for Credit Card that provides a API library.  Once you get the device and having issues writing code for it, then someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of an old question but here goes. I would recommend a MagTek or IDTECH HID MSR (Magnetic Swipe Reader). MagTek's output is ASCII and IDTECH is Hex so you can decide which is easiest.

If you are unable to interface with a HID device, you could use a Keyboard Emulated (KBE) but these are less secure as anyone can swipe into it any time and read the swipe data so I would not recommend as your first choice.

What Gateway are you going to be using for your payment processing? There are many out there, and many have encryption as an option to you. Axia Payments is one but there are dozen and dozens to choose from.

The last thing you need to keep in mind is the addition of EMV or Chip and PIN or Sig in the US. If your application will be taking card present transactions, your users would be required to keep their input abot 75% to not be subject to the burdens of liability post incident.